# Problem with ivi.visa reading binary block data

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an application which communicates with a network analyser using ivi.visa from Keysight. I often work remotely where I don't have an instrument, so I decided to write an application that can respond to the SCPI commands I need. This works ok for things like "*IDN?", but when I try to receive a binary block using ReadBinaryBlockOfByte(), the call terminates when it sees a newline character in the data.

If I set TerminationCharacterEnabled to false, all reads timeout. This is mentioned in the Keysight visa.net examples, so it doesn't seem to be an option.

So how can I read binary data?